# How do I determine if the id is unique?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

What code should I type for ipython notebook to determine if the code in the ID column of a csv file is unique?

I have tried searching online but to no avail.

Comment: Could you explain your problem and requirements with an example ?

Comment: You could compare the length of `len(df) == len(df['ID'].unique())`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Do you want to know how many unique IDs there are? Do you want to get the set of unique IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest is to compare the length of the df against the length of the [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique) values:

```
len(df) == len(df['ID'].unique())
```

will yield `True` or `False`

Also you could call [`drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.Series.drop_duplicates):

```
len(df) == len(df['ID'].drop_duplicates())
```

Also [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique):

```
len(df) == df['ID'].nunique()
```

Example:

```
In [6]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,1,2,3,4]})
df
Out[6]:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  3
5  4
In [7]:

len(df) == df['a'].nunique()
Out[7]:
False
```

Another method is to invert the boolean series returned from [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated) and pass this `np.all` which will return true if all values are `True`, for this sample data we get a single `False` value hence it will yield `False`:

```
In [11]:

np.all(~df['a'].duplicated())
Out[11]:
False
```